# Prove an abstract function is constant

Tags: analysis

Question:
If second order derivable function $f$ is a solution of equation $f'' + f = 0$, prove: $f^2 + (f')^2$ is constant.

My struggle:
Let $g(x) = f(f(x)) + f'(f'(x))$, derivation $g'(x) = f'(f(x))f'(x) + f''(f'(x))f''(x)$, get formula a, then try to prove $g'(x) = 0$.

Because $f'' + f = 0 => f''(x) = -f(x)$, get formula b and $f'' + f = 0 => f''(f'(x)) + f'(x) = 0 => f''(f'(x)) = -f'(x)$, get formula c. let formula b and c substitute formula a get $g'(x) = f'(f(x))f'(x) + f(f'(x))f(x)$.

Final I stuck here.

Comment: $f^{2}$ is supposed to be  square, not a composition.

Comment: @geetha290krm thank you for your hint.

Comment: Personally I'd multiply the given DE by $f'$ and integrate.

Comment: thanks for all helps. I have proved the conclusion finally.

Comment: @ancientmathematician sorry for my stupid, what is DE.

Comment: Differential equation. $f''+f=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Half the derivative of $f^2+(f')^2$ is
$$ff'+f'f''.$$
Can you prove it is zero?

Comment: Yes, I have proved it. Thank you for your enthusiasm answer.